# Why does this not render a cube with a texture on all sides bevy?

Tags: rust, 3d, bevy

I'm trying to render a cube with a texture on all sides in bevy. The texture is `16x16` and the cube is `1` bevy coordinate large.
This is my code so far:

```rust
use bevy::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    App::new()
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins.set(WindowPlugin {
            window: WindowDescriptor {
                title: "Definitely Minecraft".to_string(),
                ..Default::default()
            },
            ..Default::default()
        }))
        .add_startup_system(setup_system)
        .add_startup_system_to_stage(StartupStage::PostStartup, generate_world_system)
        .run();
}

#[derive(Resource)]
struct GameMaterials {
    dirt: Handle<StandardMaterial>
}

fn setup_system (
    mut commands: Commands,
    asset_server: Res<AssetServer>,
    mut materials: ResMut<Assets<StandardMaterial>>,
) {
    // Light
    commands.spawn(DirectionalLightBundle {
        transform: Transform::from_xyz(4., 80., 4.),
        ..Default::default()
    });

    commands.insert_resource(GameMaterials {
        dirt: materials.add(StandardMaterial {
            base_color_texture: Some(asset_server.load("dirt.png")),
            alpha_mode: AlphaMode::Blend,
            unlit: false,
            ..Default::default()
        })
    });

    // Camera
    commands.spawn(Camera3dBundle {
        transform: Transform::from_xyz(3., 5., 8.).looking_at(Vec3::ZERO, Vec3::Y),
        ..Default::default()
    });
}

fn generate_world_system(
    mut commands: Commands,
    game_materials: Res<GameMaterials>,
    mut meshes: ResMut<Assets<Mesh>>,
) {
    let block_handle = meshes.add(Mesh::from(shape::Cube::new(1.)));

    commands.spawn(PbrBundle {
        mesh: block_handle.clone(),
        material: game_materials.dirt.clone(),
        transform: Transform::from_xyz(0., 0., 1.5),
        ..Default::default()
    });
}
```

When I compile I get a `1x1` cube with a blurry (the actual texture is sharp) texture on a single side. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: I can not reproduce this with bevy 0.9. I get a normal cube with texture on all three visible sides. Are you sure this does not seem like there is only one side due to lighting?

Answer (score 0):

By [default](https://docs.rs/bevy_render/0.9.1/bevy_render/texture/struct.ImagePlugin.html#structfield.default_sampler) Bevy uses linear sampling which makes the low resolution textures blurry. You can change the sampler so that the textures look pixelated:

```
DefaultPlugins.set(ImagePlugin::default_nearest())
```